# What is the Difference between VSO, VSTS and Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, saas

TFS is on-premise, all these 3 are online. This is clear.

What I don't understand is: What is the difference between these 3?

- VSO
- VSTS
- Azure DevOps

It seems they are all the same, but I guess I miss something.

Comment: They are all different names for the same service. It's been renamed about 6 times now. Azure DevOps is the current name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These three names actually refer to the same service. Both vso and vsts are the former names of azure devops.

On November 2015, Microsoft announced the transition of its Visual Studio Online (VSO) service to the name Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) which better describes the role that it has as the platform for DevOps delivery. You can refer to this [blog](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/november-2015/what-the-visual-studio-online-(vso)-rename-to-visu).

On September 10, 2018, Microsoft renamed Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to Azure DevOps Services. See the details about the rename [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/what-is-azure-devops?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#vsts).

Comment: Thanks, the question is whether Azure DevOps doesn't CONTAIN Vso and more stuff. I was asked to study Vso, and I don't want to study other unnecessary things due to lack of time.

Comment: Do you refer to [Visual Studio Codespaces](https://www.windowscentral.com/visual-studio-online-now-visual-studio-codespaces-and-lower-prices-are-way)?  Visual Studio Codespaces is being retired. To use codespaces in the future,sign up for [Github early access](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/visual-studio-online/).

Comment: No, VSO for Visual Studio Online. I would like to know if Azure DevOps contain more things than VSO, in order to prevent a situation when I study things I don't need.

Comment: If the VSO here refers to the former name of azure devops instead of Visual Studio Codespaces, azure devops naturally contains more things than VSO, and some of the functions of VSO have also been eliminated in azure devops.

Comment: And VSS (e.g. `vss-extension.json`, when you [create an Azure DevOps extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops)) stands for Visual Studio Services ([proof](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/b22b4754888ffcf89af1944606585ae7748c15bc/bower.json#L3)).

Comment: Also, see this permalink to the article of September 10, 2018: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/ed7012f428a506189f4b8503e43bced367fa0057/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch.md?plain=1#L6